# Populate a multidimensional array (recursive relationship) from query

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to populate a multidimensional array that would support the following recursive relationship (the DATA is coming from a database table).

This multidimensional array would be used to generate the list below.  I have minimal experience with multidimensional arrays in VB.NET.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If you think there's a better way to achieve this, let me know.

DATA

```
ID      NAME                PARENTID
10      Bobby Brown         50          
20      Dave Matthew        80
30      Sergey Boostad      50
40      Linda View          50
50      Bill Lumberg        
60      Rina Gina           50
70      Ben Thompson        100
80      Maria Tree          50
90      Gustav Duffield     80
100     Jon Theodore        
110     Cedric Loomis       100 
120     Jeremy Oscar        100
```

OUTPUT (to achieve)

```
[50] - Bill Lumberg
    [10] - Bobby Brown
    [30] - Sergey Boostad
    [40] - Linda View
    [60] - Rina Gina
    [80] - Maria Tree
        [20] - Dave Matthew
        [90] - Gustav Duffield
[100] - Jon Theodore    
    [70] - Ben Thompson
    [110] - Cedric Loomis       
    [120] - Jeremy Oscar
```

Comment: It would be more appropriate to either use a custom class with these properties or a `DataTable`.

Comment: Agreed.  Does this *HAVE* to be a multi-dimensional array?  If not, I would strongly recommend against it.

Comment: Tim.  I can easily put the data into a DataTable but how can I build the recursive relationship (output wanted)? I have tried to use the "DataRelation" class but it will only handle one relationship (one level).
DataRelation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation.aspx

Comment: Steven. What do you think would be the best solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store a tree in memory, you can create a class like this:

```
Public Class NameNode
    Public Sub New(name As String)
        Me.Name = name
    End Sub

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Level As Integer
    Public Property Children As New List(Of NameNode)
End Class
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
Dim bill As New NameNode("Bill Lumberg")
bill.Children.Add(New NameNode("Bobby Brown")
bill.Children.Add(New NameNode("Sergey Boostad")
```

To fill it from a flat `DataSet`, you'd need to make a recursive method, for instance:

```
Public Function BuildNode(data As DataSet, nameId As Integer, level As Integer), As NameNode
    Dim node As New NameNode()
    node.Level = level
    ' Find name with the ID in the dataset and set the node's name property accordingly
    Dim childIds As New List(Of Integer)
    ' Search Get a list of all the name ID's that have the current ID as their parent
    For Each i As Integer In childIds
        node.Children.Add(BuildNode(data, i, level + 1))
    Next
    Return node
End Function
```

Then you could build the whole Bill Lumberg branch by calling it like this:

```
Dim bill As NameNode = BuildNode(data, 50, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Steven.  I will adapt your solution with my dataset.  Would it be easy to add the level to NameNode ? For instance, "Bill Lumberg" would be a level "0"

Comment: Yes, that's easy to do.  I updated my example to show how that could be done.

Comment: Thanks Steven.  Still trying to adapt my code to make it work with your solution. Thanks again for your help.